# C#: Get a child class's nested type by name, when that child class inherits from a base class that holds those nested types

Tags: c#, reflection, nested, inner-classes, system.reflection

First off, I fully realize this is a bit strange and probably not optimal, but I'm still looking for a way to do it  :)

I have a class similar to this:

```
public class Fruit {
  public class Seed { } 
  public class Pit { } 
}
```

Then I have a subclass that inherits:

```
public class Avocado : Fruit {}
```

Elsewhere in the code, I have a string that says "Avocado.Pit", and I need to get that exact Type.

`typeof(Fruit).GetNestedTypes()` does in fact contain `Seed` and `Pit`, but `typeof(Avocado).GetNestedTypes()` returns empty though, as `Seed` and `Pit` are on `Fruit`, not on `Avocado` (this is expected: even though `Avocado` inherits from `Fruit`, the documentation for `GetNestedTypes()` mentions that nested classes that come from the base type are omitted).
If I manually try `new Avocado.Pit();` or `SomeGenericMethod<Avocado.Pit>();`, it does work as expected, so it seems like this should be possible.

So how can I do something like:

```
System.Type desiredType = System.Type.GetNestedTypesIncludingInherited("Avocado.Pit");
// desiredType.FullName would be Avocado.Pit, not Fruit.Pit.
```

I expect the real way will require a few more hoops to jump through, but that's fine; is this possible? Thanks very much!

Comment: There does not exist any type named `Avocado.Pit` in your code. When you mention `Avocado.Pit`, what is really referenced in the compiled code is `Fruit.Pit`, and `Object.ReferenceEquals(typeof(Avocado.Pit), typeof(Fruit.Pit))` will confirm it at runtime if you can't check a decompile. That you can mention nested types with qualified names of derived types is something the compiler throws in for fun (probably for consistency with members) but has no basis in the .NET type system. Now, you can write a method that will spit out `Avocado.Pit` anyway, but the question is what you'd do with it.

Comment: Hm this is interesting, thanks @JeroenMostert. My goal is to be able to create a generic method like `Prepare<T>() where T : Fruit {}` that will be able to get the pit type dynamically:

So if I were to pass `Prepare<Avocado>()`, in the body of the Prepare method I need to find a way to do something like `System.Type pitType = typeof(T).GetNestedTypesIncludingFromBase("Pit");`

Hopefully at that point, `pitType.FullName` would be `Avacado.Pit`.

(I think my example fruit metaphor is breaking down a bit haha but hopefully that shows you what I mean). Thanks again! :)

Comment: But as I've pointed out this is unnecessary because there is only the single type. You can simply write `Type pitType = typeof(Fruit.Pit)`. And yes, this also means you can use `Avocado.Pit` wherever you'd expect `Peach.Pit`, whether that's desirable or not. If you want/need type safety for those types you have to get trickier. The correct approach would depend on what those types are supposed to accomplish (beyond abstract `Fruit`s). It's probable a practical solution would not involve nested types at all (at least not publicly exposed ones).

Comment: Thanks again @JeroenMostert, this is helpful! If there's no real way to differentiate between `Avocado.Pit` or `Peach.Pit`, then this probably won't work; to answer your question though, let's go back to that `Prepare<T>()` method: let's assume I'll call `Prepare<Avocado>()` somewhere. In the body of the `Prepare` method, I store the given fruit type:
`Type fruitType = typeof(T); // Type Avocado`
Then I'd like to somehow get the pitType (which since your answer I now realize isn't unique):
`Type pitType = fruitType.GetAnyNestedType("Pit"); // Ideally this is Type Avocado.Pit`

Comment: Sorry @JeroenMostert, ran out of room! The end goal in the function would be to then use a generic function with the pit type: so I could write it manually as 
`Bury<Avacado.Pit>()`, but I need a way to do that dynamically from the types above.

But the `Bury<T>()` function assumes a difference between an avocado pit and a peach pit... hypothetically, if it was possible to call Bury with the constructed generic type Avocado.Pit, would the body of the Bury function have any way to tell if it came from an avocado or a peach?

Comment: You can write such a method with a little loop walking up the inheritance chain (`while (t != null) { nestedTypes.Add(t.GetNestedTypes()); t = t.BaseType;`). Even then that method will eventually just find `Fruit.Pit`; if you know `T` is `Fruit` (through a constraint) there is no need for any dynamism because the type is static. If you just want to have the string `Avocado.Pit` (for whatever reason), it's trivially constructed as `$"{typeof(T).Name}.{nameof(Fruit.Pit)}"`. Only when both the type of `T` and the name `Pit` are only available at runtime would you need a recursive lookup.

Comment: And to your question above, `Bury<Avocado.Pit>()` would end up invoked as `Bury<Fruit.Pit>()`, no matter how you got a hold of the type you call `Avocado.Pit`. There is literally no difference because there is only a single `Pit` type in the whole system, as I've been trying to get across. :-) `Avocado.Pit`, `Peach.Pit` and `Fruit.Pit` are three names for the *same type*, just as (normally) `string`, `String` and `System.String` are the same thing and you couldn't tell what name was used in the source to refer to this type (or what call was used to obtain it if done dynamically).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I get what you're saying, thank you for taking the time to explain! I'll go try your suggestions and see if I can make this work (but it definitely sounds like a different approach would be better). I appreciate it! :D

Answer (score -1):

The program below will print your nested types:

> TypeExample.Avocado+Peel
>
> TypeExample.Fruit+Seed
>
> TypeExample.Fruit+Pit
>
> TypeExample.Fruit+Seed+InnerSeed

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TypeExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var type = typeof(Avocado);
            var types = type.RetrieveNestedTypes();

            foreach (var innerType in types)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(innerType.FullName);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Fruit
    {
        public class Seed
        {
            public class InnerSeed { }
        }
        public class Pit { }
    }

    public class Avocado : Fruit
    {
        public class Peel { }
    }

    public static class TypeHelper
    {
        public static List<Type> RetrieveNestedTypes(this Type type)
        {
            List<Type> list = new List<Type>();

            list.AddRange(RetrieveNestedInnerTypes(type));

            return list;
        }

        private static List<Type> RetrieveNestedInnerTypes(Type type)
        {
            var types = type.GetNestedTypes().ToList();

            foreach (Type innerType in types.ToList())
            {
                types.AddRange(RetrieveNestedInnerTypes(innerType));
            }

            var basetype = type.BaseType;

            if (basetype != null)
            {
                types.AddRange(RetrieveNestedInnerTypes(basetype));
            }

            return types;
        }
    }
}
```